# Why are my comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I flagged two comments on [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12673/9275):

> Is it code-golf? If so, tag it. If not, define the winning criteria.

And the second flagged comment:

> @ugoren sorry not sure where to draw the line, i want shortest within the criteria, is that challenge or golf?

And I flagged them as "obsolete", because they are obsolete: the question is tagged [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) now, so it has an objective winning criteria now.

So, why are these flags declined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I declined your flags.

My usual criterion for deciding whether to delete comments is to see whether removing them would leave other "orphan" comments that make no sense without the comments in question. If in doubt, I usually err on the side of retention.